# jsf ui:repeat with multiple items in row

Tags: jsf, facelets

Is it possible to iterate over collection and display multiple items in a row?
Something like:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{c.images}" var="img" step="3">
#{img} #{img+1} #{img+2}<br/><br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you iterate over the list and add the `<br/><br/>` for every index where `index % 3 == 0` ?

Alternatively, if you are using RichFaces, you could try and use its datagrid:

```
<rich:dataGrid 
  value="#{c.images}" 
  columns="3">
...
```

Comment: yep, I came with this idea just after posting :) but `index % 3 == 0` will print new line after first element, so it should be `index % 3 == 2`

Comment: @mm1 yes, or you have `index > 0 and index % 3 == 0` otherwise you might get the linebreaks after the last element as well, even if you wouldn't need it (like if you have 6 images).